# Carriage return in Button messes with the margin

Tags: android, android-layout, button, line-breaks

If I add a carriage return in a button an extra bit of "margin" (for a lack of better explanation) appears at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff992a2a">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Extend" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Accept
0:23"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

If I don't add the carriage return, it aligns perfectly:
[image]

how can I stop the extra 'margin' appearing ? I tried setting the `android:lines="2"` and and/or `android:singleline="false"` but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set **`android:gravity="center"`** in your `LinearLayout`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff992a2a">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Extend" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Accept
0:23" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add `LinearLayout`. You can use just `RelativeLayout`.
Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff992a2a">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Extend" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_1"
        android:text="Accept
            0:23" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: mmm some of these buttons will be dynamically shown and hidden, so the toRightOf will not work.

Comment: toRighOf will still work if any of your button will have visibility as Gone

Comment: i've been using Xamarin to dynamically show and hide the buttons using 
local:MvxBind="Visibility ExtendButtonVisible, Converter=Visibility"
and from the start noticed that i'll see errors at runtime if a toRightOf reference is hidden and so i haven't used that ever since. perhaps i need to do another trial perhaps i did something wrong.

thank you @hello World